# How to handle "Bad state: No element" in flutter DataTable row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have DataTable in flutter which is working fine until I got an empty list. In case the `widget.detailDate.brands` is empty, I get "Bad state: No element" error, now my question is, how can I handle the error, I've tried something like

```
widget.detailDate.brands.map((brand) => {
  if (brand != ' '){
    // do the DataRow stuff
  }else{
    print('brnad not found')
  }
}).toList();
```

But it's not working. I wanna add something like "-", if the list is empty

My whole code looks like this:

```
DataTable buildBrandTable(context) {
  return DataTable(
    columnSpacing: 0,
    showCheckboxColumn: false,
    columns: const <DataColumn>[
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Brand',
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Mandant',
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Januar',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Februar',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'März',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'April',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Mai',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Juni',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Juli',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'August',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'September',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Oktober',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'November',
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      )),
      DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Dezember',
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    rows: [
      ...widget.detailData.brands!
          .map(
            (brand) => DataRow(
              onSelectChanged: (bool) {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed(DetailScreen.routeName, arguments: {
                  'pageType': 'Brand',
                  'id': brand['brand_slug'].toString(),
                });
              },
              color: (brand['brand'] == 'Gesamt')
                  ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) => Colors.grey[300])
                  : null,
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text(brand['brand'])),
                DataCell(Text(brand['mandant'])),
                ..._month
                    .map(
                      (month) => DataCell(
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Text(formatter.format(brand[month])),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        formatter.format(
                          _month
                              .map((month) => brand[month])
                              .toList()
                              .reduce((a, b) => a + b),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text((brand['rate'] != null)
                          ? formatterPercent.format(brand['rate'] / 100)
                          : 'N/A'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text((brand['rate_letztes_jahr'] != null)
                          ? formatterPercent
                              .format(brand['rate_letztes_jahr'] / 100)
                          : 'N/A')
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
          .toList(),

    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: why you make condition `if (brand != ' ')` 
idk its typo or not. but do you check the `brand != white space `   ?

Comment: if the brand is string , you may check like this
`brand != null || brand.length <1`

Comment: @pmatatias thanks for your response my problem is can't add if statement in rows list. I get this error "The element type 'bool' can't be assigned to the list type 'DataRow"

Comment: my bad , not scroll whole code.

if brand is array, you have to check the length.
`brand = [ ]` is not null

Comment: `if (brand != null &&  brand!.isNotEmpty)`   how bout this?

Comment: @pmatatias my main problem is, it is letting me to the if condition

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by

```
rows: [
      ...widget.detailData.brands!
          .map( // rest of your mapping function
...
```

maybe you should

```
widget.detailData.brands.length>0 ? 
...widget.detailData.brands.map( // rest of your mapping function
:
[]
```

in your widget tree

**Update**

for example
Using the spread operator(...), adds the items individually not as a list

```
  Column(
          children: [
            ...values.map((value) {
              return Text(value);
            }),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: yeah, exactly, but don't know how fix it

Comment: It is about whole `...widget.detailData.brands`

Comment: which line exacly is the error ?

Comment: the whole code inside ``` rows: []```  because brands = [] (brands is empty array )

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable/rows.html stays it can be empty but not null, thats why I am asking specific is it due to calling variable or is it because of map function that gets null

Comment: it is because of the map function that gets an empty array.  the response from backend is: ```('brands', [])```

Comment: it's letting me add the condition

Comment: @Davood I dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this: ```if (widget.detailData.brands != null &&
              widget.detailData.brands!.isNotEmpty){

          ...widget.detailData.brands!
              .map(
.
.
.).tolist()}else{
[]
}```

Comment: but I got an error "Type: Set<DataRow>

The element type 'Set<DataRow>' can't be assigned to the list type 'DataRow' ", and no idea how to use if and else statements inside DataTable's row

Comment: using spread operator you don't need to use `toList()`. updated my answer

Comment: then you avoid array within array

Comment: @Davood did you figure it out ?

Comment: yeah man, I solved it like ```rows: (widget.detailData.brands!.isNotEmpty)
          ? [
              ...widget.detailData.brands!.map(...):  [
              DataRow(...)``` thank you

Comment: @Davood Would you mind accepting the answer if indeed it did help?